# Nesting a Listview and LinearLayout together within a LinearLayout creates ui problems

Tags: android, listview

I want my ui to be scrollable. I have a LinearLayout within which a ListView and another Linear layout are nested. Following is my code

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">


    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/list"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
        android:layout_weight="10"
        android:divider="@null"
        android:dividerHeight="0dp"
        android:paddingTop="10dp" />

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:layout_weight="5"
        android:background="@drawable/border"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginBottom="3dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="3dp"
            android:orientation="horizontal">

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Vessal Name:" />

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Maize" />
        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginBottom="3dp"
            android:orientation="horizontal">

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="ETD: " />

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="09 OCT 2014" />
        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginBottom="3dp"
            android:orientation="horizontal">

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="ETA: " />

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="89.Oct 2034" />
        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginBottom="3dp"
            android:orientation="horizontal">

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Revised ETA" />

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="9 Oct 2014" />
        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="horizontal">

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Notes/ Remarks" />

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Nice delivery" />
        </LinearLayout>
    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

The problem is that the few textviews present at the last is not visible in the ui. How can I make it visible?

Comment: You can put your LinearLayout inside a ScollView

Comment: Never make the ListView height wrap_content. You should put the LinearLayout below Listview in a separate xml, inflate it and do `listview.addFooterView(inflatedView)`.

Answer (score 0):

According to [Docs](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ScrollView.html)

> Layout container for a view hierarchy that can be scrolled by the
>   user, allowing it to be larger than the physical display. A ScrollView
>   is a FrameLayout, meaning you should place one child in it containing
>   the entire contents to scroll; this child may itself be a layout
>   manager with a complex hierarchy of objects. A child that is often
>   used is a LinearLayout in a vertical orientation, presenting a
>   vertical array of top-level items that the user can scroll through.
>
> You should never use a ScrollView with a ListView, because ListView
>   takes care of its own vertical scrolling. Most importantly, doing this
>   defeats all of the important optimizations in ListView for dealing
>   with large lists, since it effectively forces the ListView to display
>   its entire list of items to fill up the infinite container supplied by
>   ScrollView.
>
> The TextView class also takes care of its own scrolling, so does not
>   require a ScrollView, but using the two together is possible to
>   achieve the effect of a text view within a larger container.

Your `xml` would be like

```
<ScrollView>
  <LinearLayout>
    <EditText/>
    <TextView/>
  </LinearLayout>
</ScrollView>
```

**Note:** There should be only one parent layout inside a `ScrollView`